# If $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=g(a)$, and $g(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(g(x)) = \lim_{g(x)\rightarrow g(a)} f(g(x))$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

If $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=g(a)$, and $g(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(g(x)) = \lim_{g(x)\rightarrow g(a)} f(g(x))$

Is this proof for the above statement correct? If not, is the statement correct, and is there an easy proof of it? I ask because I think this would make the first proof of the 1-d chain rule on wikipedia more elegant, and it seems correct to me, but I'd like to check if I messed up.

If $g(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$ and $f(x)$ continuous at $x=g(a)$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(g(x)) = f(\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x))$. $g(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$, and so $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x) = g(a)$. Since $f$ is continuous at $g(a)$, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow g(a)} f(x) = f(g(a))$. Thus $f(g(a))$ exists. Thus 
$$
f(\lim_{g(x) \rightarrow g(a)} g(x)) = f(g(a)) = \lim_{g(x) \rightarrow g(a)} f(g(x))= f(g(a)) = f(\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x)) = \lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(g(x))
$$
QED. And so in the wikipedia proof of the chain rule, one can simply say that because $f(x)$ is differentiable (and so continuous) at $x=g(a)$, and $g(x)$ is differentiable (and so continuous) at $x=a$, then it follows that
$$
(f \circ g)'(a) = \lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f(g(x)) - f(g(a))}{x-a}
$$
$$
= \lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f(g(x)) - f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)} \frac{g(x) - g(a)}{x-a}
$$
$$
= \lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f(g(x)) - f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)} \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{g(x) - g(a)}{x-a}
$$
$$
= \lim_{g(x)\rightarrow g(a)} \frac{f(g(x)) - f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)} \frac{dg}{dx}(a)
$$
$$
= \frac{df}{dg}(g(a))\frac{dg}{dx}(a)
$$

Comment: No. Your "proof" of chain rule you gave need justification of the last two "=". See the explanation in wiki.

Comment: The thing is that $g(x)-g(a)$ might vanish on every neighborhood $0<|x-a|<\delta$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof for continuity of composition of functions is not rigorous enough as you kept repeating
that $\lim_{x \to a}f(g(x))= f\left( \lim_{x \to a}g(x) \right)$ without actually
proving this fact. It should be better if you prove this by following the 
definition of limits.

Even with the continuity of composition of functions, the chain rule cannot be 
proven like that. To explain this, let's review the definition of limit:

**Definition.** A function $f:\mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ is said to be continuous at $a$ if for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $0\color{red}{<}|x-a|<\delta$.

Notice the that the definition does not require anything about $f(a)$. In particular, $f$ can be continuous at $a$ while $f(a)$ is any number.

---

Now, let's back to your proof of the chain rule. Note that the limit $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(g(x))-f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)}$ may be undefined even if we know that $f$ is differentiable at $x=g(a)$, i.e. $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-f(g(a))}{x-g(a)}$ exists.

In particular, if $g(x)=g(a)$ for all $0<|x-a|<\delta$ for some $\delta>0$ then 
$\frac{f(g(x))-f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)}$ is undefined, which means the limit 
$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(g(x))-f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)}$ is undefined.

On the other hand, $f$ is differentiable at $g(a)$ means $\lim_{x \to a} 
\frac{f(x)-f(g(a))}{x-g(a)}$ exists. Observe that $\frac{f(x)-f(g(a))}{x-g(a)}$ is always defined for any $x$ so $0<|x-g(a)|<\delta$.

Comment: Well I took that limit statement in your second sentence to be true because I know it is. I wasn't looking to prove everything, just to have a correct proof. When you say "if $g(x) = g(a)$... which means the limit does not exist", that's not true. Undefined =/= DNE. Also the assumption isn't "f is diff'able at x=a", but that "f is diff'able at x=g(a)".

Comment: @Striker Thanks, edited. For the first part, I think you need to prove that limit statement because it is equivalent to the statement about continuity of composition of functions (the limit statement is not true without the continuity of $g$ and of $f$). Hence, if you just use that limit statement to prove the original problem then you have accidentally assumed the the original problem to be true from the beginning.