# Prove using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition that if $g$ continous in $a$ and that if $f$ continuous in $g(a)$ then $f\circ g$ is continuous in $a$

Tags: calculus, functions, solution-verification, continuity

#### Question:

Prove using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition that if $g$ continous in $a$ and that if $f$ continuous in $g(a)$ then $f\circ g$ is continuous in $a$
*Rem:* I know that there is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2903270/if-fx-is-continuous-at-x-ga-and-gx-is-continuous-at-x-a-then-l) but this not the same question of mine as I am asking a proof by definition.

#### My Answer:

1- By assumption we know that because:
(i) $g$ is continuous in $a$ we have by definition that $\forall \epsilon_1>0, \exists \delta_1 > 0 : \forall |x-a|< \delta_1 \Rightarrow |g(x)-g(a)| \epsilon_1$
(ii) $f$ is continuous in $g(a)$ we have by definition that $\forall \epsilon_2>0, \exists \delta_2 > 0 : \forall |y-g(a)|< \delta_2 \Rightarrow |f(y)-f(g(a))| < \epsilon_2$
In order to prove that $f(g(x))$ is continuous by $\epsilon - \delta$ definition  at $x=a$, we must show that $\forall \epsilon > 0 , \exists \delta > 0 : \forall |x-a| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(g(x))-f(g(a))| < \epsilon $

2- Given that $f(x)$ is continuous at $g(a)$ then according to (ii) $\forall \epsilon_2>0, \exists \delta_2 > 0 : \forall |y-g(a)|< \delta_2 \Rightarrow |f(y)-f(g(a))| < \epsilon_2$

3- Now because $g(x)$ is continuous at $a$ the definition in (i) is correct forall $\epsilon_1>0$ it is in particular true in the case for $\epsilon_1 = \delta_2 $ so in such a case we have that for $ \epsilon_1 = \delta_2  $ it exists at least one $\delta_2 > 0$ such that for $x$ verifying $|x-a| < \delta_1$ we have that $ |g(x)-g(a)| < \delta_2 = \epsilon_1$

4- Now let fixe one $\epsilon > 0 $
*according to "3-"* we can choose $\delta = \delta_1 > 0$ such that all the $x$ verifying $|x-a| < \delta_1 $ verify too that $|g(x)-g(a)| < \delta_2$
*according to "2-"* by the continuity of $f$ at $g(a)$ it implies that $|f(g(x))-f(g(a))|<\epsilon$

And this finish my prove because it is valable for any fixed $\epsilon > 0 $

Q.E.D.

Is it correct? especially part -3 and -4.

Comment: What does prove by definition mean?

Comment: @masiewpao thank for your time. You re right I ve edited my question to be more precise. The meaning is by $\epsilon - \delta$ definition. Is it more clear now?

Comment: And what exactly is the question?

Comment: @stange is my answer correct?

Comment: The solution-verification tag shouldn't be used for questions like "Is my proof correct?". Instead, you should say why you think that your proof might be incorrect.

Comment: @stange First it is not the tag i used the tag i used is proof verification tag that automatically convert to solution verification and proof verification is a valid tag for my question. Scond if you want more precision is my step 3 and 4 correct as they are the heart of my proof.

Comment: Why some people want to close my question???? I ve spent time writing it

Comment: Anyone to help?

Comment: The tag solution-verification is still wrongly placed. You still haven't said why you think your proof might have flaws.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527855/real-analysis-continuity-of-a-composition-function

Comment: @stange  I have all ready explain you that this is the website that automatically replace the tag "proof verification" with the tag "tag solution-verification". Have you any constructive useful comment to write or it just amuses you to play the picky policeman instead of helping a student and down vote undergraduate question? If you do not want to help, it is your right but you can just skip the question instead of wanting to be right absolutely.  Now go flag my comment as it seems that you like this kind of interaction.